# Backbone new view reflects old model data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My model:

```
var ListModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            title: "",
            items:new Array(),
        },
        initialize: function(){
        }
...
```

but for some reason when i do:

```
function createNew(){
    var m = new ListModel();
    console.log(m);
    [model items get modified somehow]
}
createNew()

createNew()
```

the output for the model.items are identical between the two models

Why is that?

Comment: avoid using arrays or objects in defaults, they will get passed by reference, if needed initialise them in initialise function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I need to do:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.set("items", new Array());
}
```

instead of doing it in default

Comment: Or use a function for `defaults`: `defaults: function() { return { title: '', items: [ ] } }`. Everything in the `extend` argument is attached to the model's prototype so exactly the same `defaults` object will be shared (and shallow copied) by all instances.